# Why can't I change the color of a JButton with setBackground?

Tags: java, jbutton

I am using the method `setBackground()` on my `JButton` to change its color, but it doesn't change.

The code I am using

```
mybutton.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Comment: Can we see more of the code where you are trying to do this? It works for me.

Comment: Buttons are filled with a different effect other then there background alone, true using setContentAreaFilled and make sure the button is opaque

Comment: check button.isOpaque() and make sure it is true. Also, be sure you are doing this on the event thread.